# System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing this error that telling me I'm using an illegal variable or number and it highligh this line in my code `Line 34:rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();`. I think I have the issue in the parameters that need to be changed based on Oracle format but not sure. I did replace all the `@` with `p.Course_id`, then `?p.course`, `p_course_id` as I did in my stored procedure in oracle but none of them work. I'm still getting same error.
Please help me sort out this issue. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.OracleClient;



public class PostForum
{
    public static int INSERTforum(int course_Id, string question, string posterName, DateTime blog_date)
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        using (OracleConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("INSERTforum", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add("@course_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = course_Id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@question", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = question;
            command.Parameters.Add("@posterName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = posterName;
            command.Parameters.Add("@blogdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = blog_date;


            rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return rowsAffected;

    }
}
```

Here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTforum(
       p_course_id IN forum.COURSE_ID%TYPE,
       p_question IN forum.QUESTION%TYPE,
       p_postername IN forum.POSTERNAME%TYPE,
       p_blogdate IN forum.BLOG_DATE%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO forum ("COURSE_ID", "QUESTION", "POSTERNAME", "BLOG_DATE") 
  VALUES (p_course_id, p_question,p_postername, p_blogdate);

  COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Comment: when I remove all the @ it still gives me the same error and it adds another error wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTFORUM'

Comment: To help with that, we'd need to see the definition (or at least the parameter list, with types) for the `INSERTforum` stored procedure.

Comment: Are you tried to use OracleDbType for your parameters type instead of SqlDbType?

Comment: Steve; yes I need to use oracle data type  instead of sql because I'm using Oracle database

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is raised by the use of an invalid enum in your Add methods calls

If you run this code, you could notice that the [OracleType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparametercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Int32 is not the same of [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
OracleType e = OracleType.Int32;
int i = (int)e;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());   // Output = 28
SqlDbType z = SqlDbType.Int;
i = (int)z;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());   // Output = 8
```

So, I suggest to use the correct enum for your ADO.NET provider.

It is interesting to note that calling Add with `SqlDbType` instead of `OracleType` is accepted and don't raise a compiler time error. This happens because the Add method has an overload that accepts an object as second parameter (It is used to pass directly a value when constructing the parameter).

An alternative is to use `AddWithValue` of the `OracleParameterCollection`

```
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course_Id", course_Id);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", question);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posterName", posterName);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blogdate", blog_date);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the first code I couldn't understand to be honest, but eh second solution I used and nothing changed it still giving me same error.I have added stored procedure that I have hopefully it can clarify my error. thx

Comment: I see, it will be usefull to see the datatype of the fields in the table `forum` also